# Simple Programmatic Authentication Against Azure AD Needed

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, azure-active-directory

We have an Angular app running against an ASP.NET Core back end.  We want to present our users with a login screen on the Angular app that collects a username and password, and sends it to a controller method on our back end.

That controller method then needs to authenticate the user against Azure AD programmatically on the back end.  If they successfully authenticate, we will then read from our own database to get their roles, and programmatically add claims. Finally we will build a JWT token to store their identity and return it to the client.

The Angular app will then add the token to its headers, and the core app will authenticate API request with that token.

In short we want to authenticate against Azure AD, and Authorize against our own database.  We don't want to forward them to an Azure web page to login, then have Azure forward them back to our app.  We want everything done on our backend to make the UX as seamless as possible.

I thought this would be super easy.  There's a TON of documentation from Microsoft with various examples on how to use ADAL.NET with Azure AD, but none of them do what we need.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? All you have done is stated what you want to do.

Comment: It's a specific problem.  The question is how do I do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems you want to collect the user credentials in Angular app and post to .net core back end , then finish the authentication in back-end app .

You can use [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) . But that is **not recommended** because The ROPC flow requires a high degree of trust and user exposure and you should only use this flow when other, more secure, flows can't be used.

Also :

> - The Microsoft identity platform endpoint only supports ROPC for Azure AD tenants, not personal accounts. This means that you must use a tenant-specific endpoint (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantId_or_Name}`) or the `organizations` endpoint.
> - Personal accounts that are invited to an Azure AD tenant can't use ROPC.
> - Accounts that don't have passwords can't sign in through ROPC. For this scenario, we recommend that you use a different flow for your app instead.
> - If users need to use multi-factor authentication (MFA) to log in to the application, they will be blocked instead.

Reference :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc

Comment: That explains why I never found code samples for this.  Microsoft doesn't want you doing this.